# Jupyter notebook not properly printing the output of data frame as table column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to view the data frame loaded in the Jupyter notebook. The output is shattered and jumbled together.

```
# Import pandas
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Read in white wine data
white = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-white.csv')

# Read in red whine data
red = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv')
white.describe()
pd.isnull(red).count()
```

[image]

How to view in proper format ? is my settings are messed up?

Comment: pd.read_csv(your_file, delimiter=';') 
read_csv expect comma by default while your delimiters are semicolon

Comment: red = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv, sep=';'')

Answer (score 0):

should add delimiter=';'
while reading file

```
white = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-white.csv', delimiter=';')
```